# Learning Haskell syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax

I learn Haskell, but got stuck on one thing:

```
add 0 = id
add x = add(x-1) . (+1)
```

This function adds one argument to another by adding 1 to the first argument and subtracting 1 from the second argument.

```
*Main> add 4 2
6
```

But, I do not really understand how does it work! Can anybody explain WHY we write 2 numbers after 'add' (while it is described only with one parameter 'x'), WHAT do the '.' and '(+1)' in the second line mean and HOW does all this work?

Thank You!

UPD: Thanks again for all the answers! Now I understand how it works :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All functions in Haskell are curried, meaning that they actually only take one parameter. When functions take two parameters, like `f a b` what's actually happening is `(f a) b`: `f a` is returning a function that is then applied to `b`.

So `add 4` is the same as `add(3) . (+1)`. `(+1)` is syntax for a function that takes its input and adds 1 to it. The `.` is a way of composing functions: `(f . g) x` is the same as `f (g x)`. So `add(3) . (+1)` first adds 1 to its argument and then calls `add(3)` on the result.

`add(3)` is then expanded to `add(2) . (+1)`, and this continues recursively until `add 0`, which evaluates to `id`. `id` is the identity function, which just returns whatever you pass to it. So `add 0 x` is `id x` is `x`.

Comment: Yes. Please don't write `f(x)` style function applications though, also not for number arguments – it just keeps up the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

I like Alec's answer. Usually when I see these type of code, I
manipulate them in these steps. Original code:

```
add 0 = id
add x = add(x-1) . (+1)
```

Let's translate it to a much easier form:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add 0 num = id num
add num1 = add (num1 - 1) . (\num2 -> num2 + 1)
```

More easier translation:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add 0 num = id num
add num1 = \num3 -> add (num1 - 1) ((\num2 -> num2 + 1) num3)
```

Another transformation:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add 0 num = id num
add num1 = \num3 -> add (num1 - 1) (num3 + 1)
```

Final transformation:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add 0 num = id num
add num1 num3 = add (num1 - 1) (num3 + 1)
```

The `.` is a function composition operator. `(+1)` is a special syntax
and represents `\x -> x + 1`.